# Firebreath 2.0 Plugin crashed in IE8

Tags: c++, activex, firebreath

IE8 crashed when access any property or method of plugin, and plugin work fine in IE10 and 11.

I have found the crash reason:
In IE8, the m_settled of ComPromise is still false for some reason. 
When ComPromise Object destroy, the destroy method calls ComPromise::_onError and crash.

```
--- a/src/ActiveXCore/ComPromise.h
+++ b/src/ActiveXCore/ComPromise.h
@@ -53,7 +53,7 @@ namespace FB { namespace ActiveX {

         void Invalidate() {
             if (!m_settled) {
-                _onError(std::runtime_error("Invalidated"));
+                //_onError(std::runtime_error("Invalidated"));
             }
             m_promise.invalidate();
         }
```

After comment the code, the IE doesn't crash and return script_error(Method invoke failed) when I access the version of plugin.
In debug mode, the HRESULT is 0x80020003 in IDispatchAPI.cpp(478).

Comment: You're going to have to do some debugging yourself.  I'll be on some of the day in the IRC room (#firebreath on freenode) and can give you feedback on your findings.  Remember that if I don't respond right away it's because I have a job and other responsibilities but might be back later if you stick around.

Comment: @taxilian Thanks for your reply. I have added some information. The m_settled of ComPromise is still false in IE8. I think this is the key of this problem.